# Switching BG using Python

Tags: python, list, background, iteration

I'm writing a simple program that changes my background when I run it.
I'm trying to make it so that when I run it, it changes the background then when I run it again it goes to the next image in the list and so on.

But I can't figure out how to make it so that each time I run it, it picks the next image in the list and assigns it to the image variable.

Here is my code:

```
Img_list = ['C:\BG\mod_bg.bmp','C:\BG\BGMATRIX.jpg'] #Image List

pathToImg = #image name here
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20  
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathToImg,
                                       0)
```

so the first time I run it I want it to use `C:\BG\mod_bg.bmp`then close then the next time I open it I want it to use `C:\BG\BGMATRIX.jpg` and close

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you will have to save the index in `Img_list` of the current picture somewhere. When your program starts it reads the index value, changes it and writes it back.

Places where you could store it are e.g.

- a (hidden) file
- the windows registry